# Adding a objective-c native project designed with UIKit, into react native project

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, unity-game-engine, uikit

I have a external project written in objective-c only. It's designing is done with the UIKit in the ViewController. This project has a few buttons in the initial screen and on button click, a unity project will be loaded.
I want integrate this entire project as a feature to react native.
What is the best approach for integrating this ios project into my react native ?
If i import the entire project into RN, how can the bridge module and the ViewController communicate each other ?
Any example or references will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance